# W3C validation for server-side form tag

Tags: asp.net, html, w3c-validation

I've checked my website html validation in w3.org and got this error

> Bad value for attribute action on element form: Must be non-empty.

but my form is asp.net server-side form and I can't set action atribute.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an old post, but for future reference in ASP.NET one can do the following to avoid blank action attributes:

```
<form action="#" runat="server">
```

This will validate with W3C and does not require you to do any special coding to detect the page url you are currently on.

Comment: Actually, this is problematic.  If you attempt to do a post with the action="#" solution, you'll get an HTTP verb server-side error.

Comment: @abegosum I've been using this solution for a while now in ASP.NET without your reported problem, any idea of why this happens?

Comment: May be a problem with the version or setting of IIS (I suspect it's a security setting to prevent certain types of script injection)?  Is your page doing any postbacks?

Comment: @abegosum Yes, postbacks are also ok. Perhaps you should list your setup and I can try and recreate your bug?

Answer (score 7):

```
form1.Action = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

this is working for me

Answer (score 2):

Omit the attribute `action`. According to HTML5 drafts, it is not required, but if present, its value must be non-empty. Reference: WHATWG HTML5 draft, [description of `action` attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fs-action).

Comment: In ASP.NET you cannot omit the action attribute, if you code

<form runat="server">

it will render as

<form action=""> ; its just the way it works.

See my response for a better solution.

Comment: Every time I learn something new about ASP.NET I hate it some more.